# data is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick Uncaught ReferenceError: javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `button` with an `onclick` attribute. On click of the `button` it opens a popup (`myModel`). The other button is a delete button. However as I click on the button it shows this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```js
$('body').on('click', 'input.deleteDep', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

function data(id) {
  $.post('data.php', {
    id: id
  }, function(r) {
    $('#myModal').html(r);
  });
}

function getData(id, file_name, div_name) {
  $.post(file_name, {
    id: id
  }, function(r) {
    $(div_name).html(r);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="data('[patientId]')">View</button>
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="getData('[patientId]','php/delete_patient.php','')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteDep" />
```

Comment: Please add the html structure to the snippet

Comment: Your sample above should (and does) work. In your actual code, have you defined the `data()` function within a `$(document).ready()` event handler? If so that's your issue - its out of scope of the `on*` event attribute

Comment: This is working properly on my wamp server. But not on hostgator server. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I think you have your functions in your `window.onload=function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){`. If so, please put your functions in your `<head>` section outside your `window.onload` and see if you get the error or not.